# Creating a GridView based on user input using a for loop

Tags: android

I am trying to create a GridView that is based on the user input. 
If the users input is x then the GridView shall show x elements. The problem is I don't want to have elements in GridView that starts with 0, as an Array in Java starts with index 0.

Here is a code snippet:

```
int numberOfTables=10; //let's say this is user input
String[] gridViewStrings = new String[numberOfTables];
for(int i =0; i<numberOfTables; i++){
    gridViewStrings[i]="Table " +i;
```

The table descriptions should not start with 0, it should start with 1.
I tried to increment the array size by +1 but I get a BoundofException.

When you compile the code the output is :
Table0, Table1, Table2,...,Table9

The output I want is :
Table 1, Table2,...,Table10

How can I handle this ?

Comment: If you just want an output Table 1 when `i` is zero and so on, why not just write `i+1` in the code `"Table "+(i+1)`

Comment: @PradyumanDixit thank you, sometimes one is unable to see the wood for the trees :P

Comment: @BInpwr no worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

`for(int i =1;i<numberOfTables; i++){ }`
Try making your i to be 1. This might make the loop start at one not zero. and you moght not get an error
or you can try `i+1`